# heroku db:push issue

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I am having some issues getting db:push to work with heroku.

As I have read else where, there is an issue with ruby versions > 1.9.3-p0, so I've downgraded to 1.9.2-p290, as it seems that that is the most common suggestion.

This can be confirmed via running ruby -v and getting `ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin11.4.0]`

```
[teacherjoy (master)]$ heroku db:push
Loaded Taps v0.3.24
Auto-detected local database: sqlite://db/development.sqlite3
Warning: Data in the app 'teacherjoy' will be overwritten and will not be recoverable.

 !    WARNING: Destructive Action
 !    This command will affect the app: teacherjoy
 !    To proceed, type "teacherjoy" or re-run this command with --confirm teacherjoy

> teacherjoy
Sending schema
Schema:        100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:05
Sending indexes
users:         100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:02
schema_migrat: 100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:01
Sending data
4 tables, 76 records
holders:         0% |                                          | ETA:  --:--:--
Saving session to push_201207160342.dat..
!!! Caught Server Exception
HTTP CODE: 500
Taps Server Error: PGError: ERROR:  time zone displacement out of range: "2012-07-10 12:00:00.000000+5894685600"
["/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:175:in `async_exec'", 
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:175:in `block (2 levels) in execute'", 
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/database/logging.rb:28:in `log_yield'", 
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:175:in `block in execute'", 
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:158:in `check_disconnect_errors'", 
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:175:in `execute'", 
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:240:in `block (2 levels) in execute'", 
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:71:in `hold'",      
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:226:in `synchronize'", 
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:240:in `block in execute'", 
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:261:in `check_database_errors'", 
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:238:in `execute'", 
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/database/query.rb:71:in `execute_dui'", 
 "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/dataset/actions.rb:552:in `execute_dui'", 
 "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/dataset/actions.rb:243:in `block (2 levels) in import'", 
 "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/dataset/actions.rb:243:in `each'", 
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/dataset/actions.rb:243:in `block in import'", 
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/database/query.rb:223:in `_transaction'", 
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/database/query.rb:209:in `block in transaction'", 
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:84:in `hold'", 
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:226:in `synchronize'", 
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/database/query.rb:207:in `transaction'", 
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/dataset/actions.rb:243:in `import'", 
"/app/lib/taps/data_stream.rb:315:in `import_rows'", 
"/app/lib/taps/data_stream.rb:158:in `fetch_remote_in_server'",           
"/app/lib/taps/server.rb:114:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Server>'",  
"/app/lib/taps/utils.rb:161:in `call'", "/app/lib/taps/utils.rb:161:in `server_error_handling'", 
"/app/lib/taps/server.rb:112:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Server>'",   
"/app/lib/taps/db_session.rb:15:in `block in conn'",  
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:76:in `connect'", 
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sequel-3.20.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:119:in `connect'",   
"/app/lib/taps/db_session.rb:14:in `conn'", 
"/app/lib/taps/server.rb:111:in `block in <class:Server>'",    
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:865:in `call'",  
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:865:in `block in route'", 
 "/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:521:in `instance_eval'", 
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:521:in `route_eval'",  
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:500:in `block (2 levels) in route!'", 
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:497:in `catch'",    
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:497:in `block in route!'", 
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:476:in `each'",   
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:476:in `route!'", 
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:601:in `dispatch!'", 
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:411:in `block in call!'", 
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:566:in `instance_eval'", 
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:566:in `block in invoke'", 
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:566:in `catch'",    
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:566:in `invoke'", 
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:411:in `call!'", 
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:399:in `call'", 
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:979:in `block in call'", 
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1005:in `synchronize'",   
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:979:in `call'",   
"/home/heroku_rack/lib/static_assets.rb:9:in `call'",   
"/home/heroku_rack/lib/last_access.rb:15:in `call'", 
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:47:in `block in call'",   
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:41:in `each'", 
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:41:in `call'",  
"/home/heroku_rack/lib/date_header.rb:14:in `call'",   
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:77:in `call'",  
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/connection.rb:76:in `block in pre_process'", 
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/connection.rb:74:in `catch'",   
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/connection.rb:74:in `pre_process'",   
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/connection.rb:57:in `process'",  
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/connection.rb:42:in `receive_data'", 
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run_machine'", 
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run'",   
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:57:in `start'",  
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/server.rb:156:in `start'", 
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:80:in `start'", 
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/runner.rb:177:in `run_command'",   
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/lib/thin/runner.rb:143:in `run!'",  
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.7/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'", 
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:19:in `load'",   
"/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:19:in `<main>'"]
```

What is causing this issue and/or how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly what fixed it, but I was trying to push via a local seeds file. When I tried to run db:seed, I kept getting migration errors. When I tried to run the migrations, I got migration errors. So I ran the following: and then kept running db:migrate as I got new errors.

```
heroku run rake db:reset
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is due to date format of holders table(field is time zone displacement).

Comment: How would I begin to fix that? And are you suggesting that I have a field called time zone displacement?